# Lifting isomorphisms between linear categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $C$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear category, such that $C(x,y)$ is a free abelian group with finite rank, for every $x,y\in\mathrm
{Ob}(C)$. Given a commutative ring with identity $R$, let $RC$ denote the category with the same objects of $C$, and morphisms $RC(x,y):=R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} C(x,y)$.

Does any isomorphism in $\mathbb{F}_pC(x,y)$ lift to an isomorphism in $\mathbb{Z}^{\wedge}_pC(x,y)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to show that you can lift isomorphisms along $AC\to BC$ whenever $A\to B$ is a square zero extension. (EDIT : here I'm using finite generation of $C(y,x), C(x,y)$ to obtain that $\mathbb Z_p\otimes C(x,y)$ is $p$-adically complete)

So let $\sum_i b_i\otimes f_i \in BC(x,y)$ be an isomorphism, with inverse $\sum_j d_j\otimes g_j$.

Choose lifts $\tilde b_i, \tilde d_j$ in $A$ of $b_i, d_j\in B $. Then $(\sum_i \tilde b_i\otimes f_i)\circ (\sum_j \tilde d_j \otimes g_j) = id_y + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \in \ker\otimes C(y,y)$, where $\ker$ is the kernel of $A\to B$. Indeed, because $C(y,y)$ is flat, $\ker\otimes C(y,y)$ is in particular the kernel of $A\otimes C(y,y)\to B\otimes C(y,y)$ (EDIT: as R. van Dobben de Bruyn pointed out, I'm not using flatness here, just right exactness of the tensor product).

In particular, because $\ker^2 = 0$, you find that $\epsilon\circ \epsilon = 0$, and so $id_y + \epsilon$ is invertible in $A\otimes C(y,y)$. In particular, $\sum_i \tilde b_i \otimes f_i$ has a right inverse, and $\sum_j \tilde d_j \otimes g_j$ has a left inverse.

Now (with the same lifts !) reasoning symmetrically (in $C(x,x)$ ) shows that they each have an inverse on the other side, so they are both isomorphisms. Either one of them is a lift, as desired.

In particular, if you were doing this over another base ring than $\mathbb Z$, really the only thing you would need is for an analogue of  $\mathbb Z_p\otimes C(x,y)$ (resp. $(y,x)$) being $p$-adically complete.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simplification of Maxime Ramzi's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/419841/82179). Given an isomorphism $\bar f \in \mathbf F_p\mathscr C(x,y)$, the claim is that *any* lift $f \in \mathbf Z_p\mathscr C(x,y)$ of $\bar f$ is an isomorphism.

Indeed, if $g \in \mathbf Z_p\mathscr C(y,x)$ is a lift of $\bar g = \big(\bar f\big)^{-1}$, we know that $gf = 1 - p\phi$ for some $\phi \in \mathbf Z_p\mathscr C(x,x)$. The series $\psi = \sum_{i=0}^\infty p^i\phi^i$ converges in $\mathbf Z_p\mathscr C(x,x)$ and gives a two-sided inverse of $gf$, so $f$ has a left inverse $\psi g$ (and $g$ has a right inverse $f\psi$). Swapping the roles of $f$ and $g$ shows that $f$ has a right inverse as well, so $f$ is invertible. $\square$

---

**Remark.** A note on the hypotheses: flatness is never used; the only role it plays in Ramzi's answer is uniqueness of $\phi$ such that $gf = 1-p\phi$, but this is inconsequential. On the other hand, it is crucial that the $\mathscr C(x,y)$ are finitely generated, as we need $\mathbf Z_p\mathscr C(x,y)$ to be $p$-adically complete [Tag [00MA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MA)(3)].

Comment: You're absolutely right, on both accounts ! I forgot to mention this $p$-completeness thing at the beginning, and I didn't realize that I wasn't actually using flatness :)